# Cannot call value method of Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

I have this:

```
public class Bootstrapper {
  public static List<Class<? extends Annotation>> annots = Arrays.asList(
    NotNull.class,
    ColumnType.class,
    RuntimeType.class,
    DefaultValue.class
  );
}
```

and then this is called in a static method:

```
  for(Class<? extends Annotation> x: Bootstrapper.annots){
      if (field.isAnnotationPresent((Class)x)) {
        Object value=  field.getAnnotation(x).value();  // doesn't compile :(
      }
  }
```

but then I get this compilation error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project vertx-start-project: Compilation failure
>   [ERROR]
>   /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx.api/src/main/java/huru/query/Bootstrapper.java:[55,50]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   method value() [ERROR]
>   location: interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation

however it will compile if I hardcode an annotation:

```
Object value=  field.getAnnotation(ColumnType.class).value();  // compiles!
```

I looked at the source, the field.getAnnotation() method looks like:

```
  public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(annotationClass);
    return (Annotation)annotationClass.cast(this.declaredAnnotations().get(annotationClass));
  }
```

Comment: The annotation class has no `value()` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html

Comment: true the value method gets supplied by each class that extends Annotation?

Comment: Not each class. Only in specific classes which supports values

Comment: Ah I need to add an interface to each Annotation that has the value method, duh